# Android calculator app crash after clicking operator without numbers

Tags: performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

i created a Calculator on Android, but if i dont input a number and i click an operation and my app will crash ans say"Unfortunetly you app name has stop", can you help solve this problem any idea to catch that exception?,...

```
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1Id);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2Id);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3Id);
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4Id);
    btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5Id);
    btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6Id);
    btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7Id);
    btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8Id);
    btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9Id);
    btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0Id);

    btnPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlusId);
    btnMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMinusId);
    btnTimes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTimesId);
    btnDivide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDivideId);
    btnModulo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnModuloId);
    btnEquals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEqualsId);
    btnCA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCAId);

    MainDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MainDisplayId);

    try{

        btn1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn5.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn6.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn7.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn8.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn9.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn0.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnPlus.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnMinus.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnTimes.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnDivide.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnModulo.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnEquals.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"1";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"2";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"3";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"4";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"5";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"6";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"7";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"8";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"9";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"0";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            op = "+";
            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            op = "-";
            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnTimes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            op = "*";
            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnDivide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            op = "/";
            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnModulo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            op = "%";
            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnEquals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            if(op=="+"){
            ans = num1 + num2;
            MainDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }else if(op=="-"){
            ans = num1 - num2;
            MainDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }else if(op=="*"){
            ans = num1 * num2;
            MainDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }else if(op=="/"){
            ans = num1 / num2;
            MainDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }else if(op=="%"){
            ans = num1 % num2;
            MainDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }
        }
    });

    btnCA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
}
enter code hereprotected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1Id);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2Id);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3Id);
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4Id);
    btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5Id);
    btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6Id);
    btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7Id);
    btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8Id);
    btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9Id);
    btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0Id);

    btnPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlusId);
    btnMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMinusId);
    btnTimes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTimesId);
    btnDivide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDivideId);
    btnModulo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnModuloId);
    btnEquals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEqualsId);
    btnCA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCAId);

    MainDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MainDisplayId);

    try{

        btn1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn5.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn6.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn7.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn8.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn9.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btn0.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnPlus.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnMinus.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnTimes.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnDivide.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnModulo.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnEquals.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"1";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"2";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"3";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"4";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"5";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"6";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"7";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"8";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"9";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btn0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getNum = MainDisplay.getText().toString();
            getNum = getNum+"0";
            MainDisplay.setText(getNum);

        }
    });
    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            op = "+";
            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            op = "-";
            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnTimes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            op = "*";
            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnDivide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            op = "/";
            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnModulo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            op = "%";
            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnEquals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(MainDisplay.getText().toString());
            if(op=="+"){
            ans = num1 + num2;
            MainDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }else if(op=="-"){
            ans = num1 - num2;
            MainDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }else if(op=="*"){
            ans = num1 * num2;
            MainDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }else if(op=="/"){
            ans = num1 / num2;
            MainDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }else if(op=="%"){
            ans = num1 % num2;
            MainDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(ans));
            }
        }
    });

    btnCA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            MainDisplay.setText("");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cramming your pile of code into a http://sscce.org/?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see where you are declaring op but I assume it is a string?

Try

```
if(op.equals("")){
//Do nothing
}
```

You also have a lot of repetition in your code and could write some methods to get rid of that repetition and rather than using hundreds of listeners just use one and some if statements